# Magento 1 retrieve customer email who ordered from specific category

Tags: orders, customer, magento-1

I need to get a list with the e-mail addresses of the customers who ordered products from a certain category, no matter if the customer is registered or not. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$purchaseCatagory = 5;

$categoyCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($purchaseCatagory)
    ->getProductCollection();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('in' => $categoyCollection->getAllIds()));

foreach ($collection as  $order) {
    $orders=$order->getOrder();
    echo $orders->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not show me any result. Thx anyways!

Comment: Did you add your category id because i tested this code amd working for me

Comment: yes, I added my category id but the screen remains blank.

Comment: is there anything I could have missed or done wrong?

Comment: Enable error log and check the error

Comment: my output `robert@gmail.com
robert@gmail.com
joe@gmail.com
jack@gmail.com
jack@gmail.com
joe@example.com
robert@example.com
robert@example.com
jack@example.com
jack@example.com
donald@example.com
albert@example.com
albert@example.com
linda@example.com
linda@example.com
linda@example.com
linda@example.com
linda@example.com
linda@example.com
kip@example.com
kip@example.com
dong@example.com
dong@example.com
dong@example.com
dong@example.com
johndoe@example.com
johndoe@example.com`

Comment: where do I have to place my file?

Comment: @SelfDiagnostics don't get you use this code anywhere **phtml** file **block** file or **controller**.where you want to show this?